# Blend-exchange not working(Please accept the terms and conditions)

Tags: bug, blend-exchange

Blend-exchange won't let me upload my file despite me accepting the terms of service[image]

Comment: Please add the OS and browser version that the error is occurring in.

Comment: google chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit) I am doing this on a windows laptop

Comment: Try removing the # sign and everything after it from question url.

Comment: That worked thank you